# How to achieve online chatting in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am new in Java development.

I Want to make chat server Application in jsp. i search at Google but i find only intranet Chatting but i want to make application that has online chatting.

Can any one give me some advice or give me some good link.

Comment: What did you find? Why is it not applicable for online chatting? IP networks are IP networks, and they are the same, intranet, or online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Netty](http://netty.io/) is a very good communications library that would be ideal for writing a chat server.

The [examples in the documentation](http://netty.io/docs/) include, for example, a secure SSL-based chat server and client.

You could, for example go for a setup like the following:

- Server runs your jsp pages plus a netty-based chat server.
- Web pages include a small Java chat applet that connects back to the chat server for realtime chatting